# No Package name given for dpkg: package is in a very bad inconsistent state;

Tags: dpkg

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/37.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

**dpkg: error processing package at (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state**; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 at
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

But it didn't tell me which package.  Any help would be appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The package was named, it was "at".

```
sudo dpkg --audit
```

It responded:
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 at                   Delayed job execution and batch processing

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall at -f


sudo dpkg --audit
```

No errors

then ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

No errors

It all started when I was trying to install a driver for my Epson WF-4630